# Does the split require two panels?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

A panel which contains two sub panels within it.  If we need to add split pane to it, must the split pane require two components?

If we insert split pane at least how many components are required?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From JavaDoc:
"JSplitPane is used to divide two (and only two) Components."

Comment: you understand this bad english from the question? wow xD. I read it 3 times and dont get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a splitpane as a panel with two child panels. One panel on the left, and one on the right.

The only difference is that there is a border between the two child panels which you can drag left or right (or top and bottom).